# Zabbix. Don't show custom item when creating custom graph

Tags: graph, triggers, monitoring, host, zabbix

On the host (which is being monitored) there is a file in which 2 values ​​either Up or Down arrive.

The Powershell script reads the value from the file and passes it to the zabbix agent, the agent already transfers it to the server.

On the server created Item which accepts these values. Set up the conversion of values ​​Up = 1, Down = 0.

Dashboard reacts as expected, when Down arrives it alarms, when Up it calms down.

Next, i need to create a custom graph based on this Item. And this is where the fun begins. When choosing an Item, the item I need is not displayed in the list offered when creating a graph ... and now I would like to understand why and what to do?

[image]
[image]

Comment: change TestStatus to numeric `type`